# Does Android support cross application file access

Tags: android, android-file

Does android support cross application file access i mean Lets say Application A created a file called
"abcd.txt", can we access the file "abcd.txt" from another application B like how it can be possible in windows and not possible in iOS. please help.

Comment: yes. just create it in any directory accessible from both apps, such as most of the external storage.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible, even multiple manners.

If both applications are from the same developer they could use the same shared user id. This is an attribute in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, [`android:sharedUserId`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid). When different applications/apks have the same userid they are able to read each others files. When using this technique, files are still prive to the rest of the OS, but are readable/writable by other apks from the same developer.

Another posibility is using the sdcard to share data. That storage is publicly available.

Android has built-in support for sharing data with other applications through the use of `ContentResolvers`. This does not work for files, but is probably the preferred way to shared data between applications.

Comment: when using the same sharedUserId, do those apps need to have the same signed certificate?

Comment: `… they will all share the same ID — provided that they are also signed by the same certificate.` So yes…

Comment: @MrSnowflake : okay thanks for your answer, and i have one more question for you please answer it, that is android uses which file system.

Comment: I believe it was ext3 in previous versions, but didn't Google switch? I don't know. But afaik it also depends on manufacturer, because Samsung is using [RFS](http://movitool.ntd.homelinux.org/trac/movitool/wiki/RFS)